# How to apply Three type of conditions in php

Tags: php

I am having the following problem.
I have two parameter that are set to enabled and disabled. and results are displayed on these parametes.

condition1:   disabled   enabled     disabled
Condition2 :  disabled   disabled     enabled
results:     allowed    no            no

I am using the following code to meet the conditions. But nothing is displayed and no errors are generated.

```
if ( condition1== disabled && condition2 == disabled ) {  // Both are disabled  Echo "Allowed";}
elseif (condition1== disabled && condition2 == enabled ) {//check for condition2 only  echo "condition 2";}
else (condition == enabled && condition2 == disabled ) {//check for condition1 only  echo "condition 1";}
```

Please support for any new logic to meet these conditions.

Comment: The code posted is not valid php. Mind posting the real code you used?

Comment: @rangad i am sorry bro, i cant post the real code. i need only the logic  if you guys can help me

Comment: Shouldn't be a real problem (if you edit the question to be clear about what you want and what you want). Just noted this as the code posted contains syntactical errors that may lead to a blank page on some configurations, which would fit your problem description. I just wanted to rule that out as a source for your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanted to do:

```
if (condition1 == "disabled" && condition2 == "disabled" ) {
  // Both are disabled
} elseif (condition1 == "enabled" && condition2 == "disabled" ) {
  // Only Condition1 is enabled
} elseif (condition1 == "disabled" && condition2 == "enabled" ) {
  // Only Condition2 is enabled
} elseif (condition1 == "enabled" && condition2 == "enabled" ) {
  // Both are enabled
}
```

Note that you forgot to close the } bracket on the second condition and you also forgot the `elseif` in the third condition. Please tell me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: you got it write bro,. I will test it now and will confirm its working

Answer (score 1):

I have a better idea; it won't take two bools, only one integer:

```
int con=0;
```

In the block where to set condition1,condition2, just replace it with the numbers:

```
0 --> both disabled
1 --> condition1
2 --> condition2
```

You can even use a switch statement on the integer with cases 0,1,2.