# How to apply Three type of conditions in php rephrased version

Tags: php

Here is my rephrased version of the question:

[How to apply Three type of conditions in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760315/how-to-apply-three-type-of-conditions-in-php/27760384#27760384)

I have two tables with status fields, set as disabled and enabled.

I want to get those two condition and throw another query based on the results.

But I am getting empty page , when i compare the results.

Below is the code i am using.

```
    $sqltable1 = "select * from table1 ";
    $result=$conn->query($sqltable1);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "row: " . $row["status"]. "<br>";
        }

    $sqltable2 = "select * from table2";
    $result=$conn->query($sqltable2);
    while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "row1: " . $row1["status"]. "<br>";
        }

        if ( $row["status"] ==  "enabled"  && $row1["status"]== "disabled"  )       {
echo "condition 1 is enabled"
        }
        elseif ( $row["status"] ==  "disabled"  && $row1["status"]== "enabled"  )   {
echo "condition 2 is enabled"
        }
        elseif ( $row["status"] ==  "enabled"  && $row1["status"]== "enabled"  )    {
echo "both conditions are enabled"

        }
        elseif ( $row["status"] ==  "disabled"  && $row1["status"]== "disabled"  )  {
echo "both conditions are disabled"

        }
```

It would be equally great if you guys can provide me with different logic to achieve this.

question:
the comparison results are not working. And empty page is disaplyed for comparisons. I need the comparison condition to work so that i can write the code further.

Comment: What is your question now? What is your goal? (BTW: your if's and elseif's are not in the while loop)

Comment: I think the answer is because it's not in the loop! Take your `}` at the end of the while loop and put it under the statements! Do you mean this?

Comment: there are two loops bro, i want to get the results and compare then both. outside the while loop.

Comment: Do you want to compare each result from each table? What if they have different length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Note: not an answer.  However it didn't fit in the comments.</strike> Apparently a real answer. Just a way of dealing with what can become an if hell:

```
$sqltable1 = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = $conn->query($sqltable1);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc());

$sqltable2 = "SELECT * FROM table2";
$result = $conn->query($sqltable2);
$row1 = $result->fetch_assoc());

$condition = $row["status"] == "enabled" ? 10 : 0;
$condition += $row1["status"] == "enabled" ? 1 : 0;

switch($condition) {
  // 1 disabled, 2 disabled
  case 00:
    // Code
    break;

  // 1 disabled, 2 enabled
  case 01:
    // Code
    break;

  // 1 enabled, 2 disabled
  case 10:
    // Code
    break;

  // 1 enabled, 2 enabled
  case 11:
    // Code
    break;
  }
```

Comment: this has worked for me .exactly what i wanted to achieve. thanks

Comment: Do you know that with your code and this, you are comparing only the **last result** from each table?

Comment: I have only one row in each table. that is used to represent status for two different items.

Comment: I am still testing this new method... I will post the results here.

Comment: *I have only one row in each table* then you can simplify it to the above code.

Comment: *does not work*. My mistake, I forgot to add `$row["status"] == "enabled"`. Does it work now?

Comment: still same , only case 00 is checked with this.

Comment: Then there must be an error somewhere, my code, your code or both. Now it's [time to debug for you](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php), something I'm unable to do from here.